# my attempt to find the dimensions of a widget results in bbox returning (0,0,0,0)

Tags: python-3.x, tkinter, tkinter-canvas

I am trying to construct a screen consisting of a variable number of image only radio buttons so the user can choose an image. I want to use a vertical scrollbar and understand a key part of coding the scrollbar is setting the scrollregion found by using bbox.  I can't get bbox to produce anything other than (0,0,0,0)

I have reduced the code as much as I am able

```
from tkinter import *
from PIL import ImageTk,Image
root = Tk()
def display():
    canvas.grid()
    image=Image.open("c:/Python/Art Images/Thumbnails/0001#Ground Swell.jpg")
    thumbnail = ImageTk.PhotoImage(image)
    thumbnail_button = Radiobutton(canvas,indicatoron=0,image=thumbnail)
    thumbnail_button.image=thumbnail #keep a reference to avoid garbage collection
    thumbnail_button.grid()
    print(root.bbox("all"))
canvas=Canvas(root)
display()
root.mainloop()
```

Comment: found a clear answer in http://stackoverflow.com/a/3092341/7432. I need to search better